# HmacSHA256 not returning same value in Java

Tags: java, encryption, encoding

I have a callback URL that receives an HMAC256 in its header and a request body.

However, when I am trying to verify request body with HMAC256 header. Both values are different.

```
public static final String SECRET = "secret_key";
public static final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";

@PostMapping("/callbackUrl")
public void receiveNotification(@RequestHeader("hmac-sha256") String hmac, @RequestBody Notification notification) {
        SecretKeySpec sKey = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(sKey);
        byte[] data = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(notification);
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data);
        String result = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(rawHmac));

        log.info("HMAC request calculated {}", result);
        log.info("HMAC received {}", hmac);
}
```

I am getting different values in info logs, when I should be getting same values:

```
HMAC request calculated w5ynJTVV1H8GNgzje91BKEIYn8n9GtRU7iNcnEr/AwE=
HMAC received P5z/Ipu71qQ4ROqExL87xfhkCz5e1WpP4ypFxtikyaE=
```

What part of code is incorrect?

**EDIT**

To check how Hmac is calculated by the sender, check this:

https://docs.cronofy.com/developers/push-notifications/authentication/

Comment: Is the HMAC part of a protocol? How was the original HMAC calculated? Just a single bit of different key or input and the output bits all differ with a 50% chance.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes https://docs.cronofy.com/developers/push-notifications/authentication/

Comment: Usually this is due to some annoying encoding differences. You've should try and calculate the digest value from the bytes that you receive in the body rather than to encode it to `Notification` and then re-encoding it using `writeValueAsBytes()`. In the end, what I presume is JSON will allow different forms, whitespaces and whatnot. The difference could be just a single end-of-line behind the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question. The issue was solved with a minor change in code. Instead of directly writing value as bytes, I first changed it to string and then read bytes from it.

Changed this:

```
    byte[] data = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(notification);
    byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data);
```

to this:

```
    String data = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(pushNotification);
    byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Thanks to [Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes) for point out in the right direction.